# Strange thin line along top of background image (only visible on specific device)!

Tags: android, border, samsung-mobile

I've spent far too many hours trying to figure this out, and I'm completely stumped. Anyone want to give this a go?

A strange thin line is appearing on a couple of my background images on the mobile version of my website, using the WPTouch platform (specifically "header-bottom" and "footer-top", where the header and footer meets the page content).

It does not appear on desktop previews, nor on iPhones, but it IS happening on my Samsung Galaxy S6.

Here is the code that is causing me trouble:

```
<div class="full-width-background">
<div class="fwb-content">
<div class="homeHeaderDescription">A refreshingly simple collection of one-pot meals and practical tips for daily self-care.</div>
<div class="homeHeaderCook"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="header-bottom"></div>
```

The problem does NOT occur when I use this same code without adding inline content, for instance like this:

```
<div class="full-width-background">
<div class="fwb-content">
</div></div>
<div class="header-bottom"></div>
```

OR when I use the header-bottom by itself:

```
<div class="header-bottom"></div>
```

Here is the CSS for the divs above...

```
.full-width-background {
margin-left: -2000px !important;
margin-right: -2000px !important;
margin-top: -35px;
}

.fwb-content {
padding-left: 2000px;
padding-right: 2000px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
border: 0px !important;
background-image: url('http://thenourishedcook.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/footer_bg.jpg');}

.header-bottom {
height: auto;
width: auto;
background-image: url('http://thenourishedcook.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/header_bottom_border.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
margin-left: -2000px !important;
margin-right: -2000px !important;
margin-top: -45px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 60px;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;}
```

The website is thenourishedcook.com, however, the mobile version is not live and requires a password to view. I'm happy to supply it privately, if someone can help...

Thanks so much!

P.S.  If I change the z-index and make .fwb-content stack on top of the .header-bottom, this does make the line go away... However, it causes a whole slew of other problems, so I'm hoping to avoid this if at all possible...

UPDATE:

I'm not sure if this was the best way to go about it, but adding the following CSS cleared it up:

```
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: repeat;
```

Comment: Figured it out.  See update on original question.

Comment: I have the same problem with a thin line at the bottom. For me the background-position property does not solve the problem.